# How do I use "App Token" type instead of "User Token" for custom audience

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token, facebook-like, facebook-marketing-api

I have successful invoke "Custom Audience" using "User Token" with the permission "ads_management"

[image]

How can invoke using "App Token" ? Not sure if needed to add permission like above as its throwing me permission error.
[image]

Edit - Do we need to request through "APP Review"
[image]

Note I have get the App token and User Token under tools.
[image]

Comment: You can not add permissions to an app token. Requests that require specific permissions, simply can't be made using an app token.

Comment: Does it mean request through  "APP Review" of the apps by submitting  requirements to Facebook ?